# Double Sum Involving Condition

Tags: summation, number-theory, conditional

I would like to compute the dimensions of some small free nilpotent Lie algebras. However, I am totally new to this and I could not figure out how to write the double sum which gives the dimension of the free nilpotent Lie algebra $L(c,n)$ of step $c$ with $n$ generators.

Long story short, I would like to learn how I can write the sum

$$\dim L(c,n) = \sum_{m=1}^{c}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{d \mid m}\mu(d)n^{m/d}$$

where $\mu$ is the Möbius function, in *Mathematica*.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe `diml[c_, n_] := Block[{j}, Sum[DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[j], n^j, j, m]/m, {m, c}]]`? If this does what you want, I'll write an answer.

Comment: @J.M. Hello. I tried this with some known values and it produced the correct values. I am sorry, since I do not know much about Mathematica this is the only way of me knowing that it works. Thank you! So please go ahead and write an answer,

Comment: No need to apologize! You are fortunate here that *Mathematica* has the necessary stuff for the computations you want to do. Give me a few, and I'll write something up.

Comment: FWIW, your inner sum equals [`JordanTotient[k, n]`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_totient_function) but unfortunately that function is not in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### A story of incremental improvement

Let's look at the OP's original expression again, for reference:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{c}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{d \mid m}\mu(d)n^{m/d}$$

Most people here are familiar with `Sum[]`, and would not have much trouble translating the outer summation into *Mathematica* syntax. The inner part,

$$\sum_{d \mid m}\mu(d)n^{m/d}$$

is not terribly familiar to those who do not do much number theory. What this basically is saying is that the terms of the sum are indexed over the   divisors of $m$. Appropriately enough, *Mathematica* does have a `Divisors[]` function. The inner sum can thus be written as

```
Sum[MoebiusMu[d] n^(m/d), {d, Divisors[m]}]
```

Summing over the divisors of a number, however, is so common a number-theoretic operation that *Mathematica* has seen it fit to provide a `DivisorSum[]` function. Thus, the inner sum can also be written as

```
DivisorSum[m, MoebiusMu[#] n^(m/#) &]
```

The story does not end here. The operation

$$\sum_{d \mid m}f(d)g(m/d)$$

frequently turns up in number-theoretic and other contexts, that it has been given a special name: **[Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution)**. *Mathematica*, fortunately, also provides a function for evaluating convolutions, called `DirichletConvolve[]`. Thus, the inner sum is most compactly expressed as

```
DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[j], n^j, j, m]
```

The function in the OP can now be implemented like so:

```
diml[c_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := Block[{j},
     Sum[DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[j], n^j, j, m]/m, {m, c}]]
```

or, using [formal symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) as suggested by The Doctor,

```
diml[c_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := 
     Sum[DirichletConvolve[MoebiusMu[\[FormalJ]], n^\[FormalJ], \[FormalJ], m]/m, {m, c}]
```

(They look messy here on SE, but should look nice when pasted into *Mathematica*.)

Here is the function in action:

```
Table[diml[c, n], {c, 5}, {n, 5}]
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 6, 10, 15}, {1, 5, 14, 30, 55},
    {1, 8, 32, 90, 205}, {1, 14, 80, 294, 829}}
```

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to `DirichletConvolve` and for this instructive answer . This is my vote :)

Answer (score 8):

Please see J.M.'s answer (in comments) using [`DirichletConvolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletConvolve.html). I would vote for this as an answer.

I present my answer:

```
l[c_, n_] :=Module[{r = Range[c]},
Total[(1/r) Total /@MapThread[MoebiusMu@#1 n^(#2/#1) & ,{Divisors /@ r, r}]]]
```

I will happily delete and vote for JM answer.

Answer (score 3):

I like J.M.'s answer and voted for it. However, it's hard to format comments, so I've posted this as an answer instead. Rather than using `Block[{j},...]`, you can use *[formal symbols](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264)* instead, used to represent a formal parameter that will *never* be assigned a value. Moreover, if you enter

```
DivisorSum[m, Function[d, MoebiusMu[d] n^(m/d)]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Divisor sum with formal variables]

you will see that *Mathematica* uses formal symbols *automatically*. Also, in many cases, I prefer to use the "map notation" for `Function` instead of `#` and `&`. For example,

[image: function notation]

is executable code for this function.

Finally, in `TraditionalForm` notation, the sum can be expressed as

[image: traditional notation]

which corresponds nicely to the original sum posted in the question. However, using `DirichletConvolve` *should* be more efficient.