# How does `DirichletConvolve` relate to Dirichlet convolution?

Tags: function-construction, number-theory, convolution

Mathematica's Help documentation on `DirichletConvolve` is economical, to say the least. It claims the function "gives the Dirichlet convolution of the expressions f and g" and that's it, except for the example

```
In[1]:= DirichletConvolve[n, n, n, m]
```

> ```
> Out[1]= m DivisorSigma[0, m]
> ```

This is going to sound stupid, but here's what I take away from the help documentation:

According to their own definition, the expression `DirichletConvolve[n, n, n, m]` convolves a function `n` with some other function also called `n` to produce an output which ignores the third `n` completely, and produces a specific function of `m` as output - even though the original two separate functions both defined by `n` have not been specified...

So, obviously I have it wrong. But I genuinely cannot make any sense of it. Specifically:

1. Dirichlet convolution convolves two functions `f[n]` and `g[n]` (with the same argument `n`) to produce `Sum[f[d]*g[n/d], Divisible[n, d]]`. Where does a fourth input quantity `m` feature in this? And where does the third quantity `n` disappear to? In some expressions, changing the third quantity does make a difference, but I can't riddle what that difference is, and why. This is because...
2. In every case, the output seems to be a sum of multiples of `DivisorSigma[0, m]` (with some of those multiples being factors of `n` derived through some equality that I'm unaware of. This is emphatically not the case with actual Dirichlet convolution, so what gives?

I'm sure that these are dumb questions and there's a simple explanation, but it isn't there in the Help documentation.

Can anyone explain, perhaps with a worked-through example? It's a big ask, I know, but I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: [A related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107652).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the following code

```
f[n_, p_] := n^p
g[n_, p_] := n*p
    
DirichletConvolve[f[n, p], g[n, p], n, 4]
```

First, we define two functions `f` and `g`. Then we compute their Dirichlet convolution.

The third argument in the Dirichlet convolution tells us that `n` is the function argument for which we want to do the convolution.
`p` on the other hand is a parameter that happens to exist in the functions but is not related to the convolution.
Changing the last line to

```
DirichletConvolve[f[n, p], g[n, p], p, 4]
```

means that we are using `p` as the variable for the convolution, whereas `n` now is some parameter.

Finally, the `4` says that we want to evaluate the resulting function at 4.
If you want to evaluate this function at the general position `m` you use

```
DirichletConvolve[f[n, p], g[n, p], n, m]
```

### Mathematical Way

Let me write this in a mathematical way:
We have two functions

$$
f \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N} \\
(n,p) \longmapsto n^p
$$

and

$$
g \colon \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \longrightarrow \mathbb{N} \\
(n,p) \longmapsto n\cdot p
$$

Now `DirichletConvolve[f[n, p], g[n, p], n, m]` evaluates

$$
(f*g)(m, p) = \sum_{d \mid m} f(d, p) g \left(\frac{m}{d}, p\right)
$$

whereas `DirichletConvolve[f[n, p], g[n, p], p, m]` evaluates

$$
(f*g)(m, p) = \sum_{d \mid m} f(p, d) g \left(p, \frac{m}{d}\right)
$$

### Example from the Documentation

If the functions `f` and `g` do not have any parameters, this looks like:

```
f[n_] := n (* or any other function depending only on n *)
g[n_] := n

DirichletConvolve[f[n], g[n], n, m]
```

This example is equivalent to the one from the documentation

```
DirichletConvolve[n, n, n, m]
```

We convolve the identity map with itself and evaluate it at `m`.

Comment: Hi @A.Z. - thank you, that makes sense - kinda... Could you explain one more thing and I'll mark it as answered? Here it is: What happens if there is no extra parameter `p`, if `f` and `g` both take argument `n` only?

Comment: I updated it a little bit. I also wanted to insert a few mathematical formulas, but apparently I have some syntax error :-(

Comment: Hi @A.Z. I'm really grateful for the detail and thought you've put into this. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Let f,g be arithmetical functions.

Then (f*g)(n), where * is Dirichlet Multiplication or Convolution is equal to:

```
DirichletConvolve[f[j],g[j],j,n]
```

and also:

```
DivisorSum[n,f[#]g[n/#]&]
```

So for example,

```
DivisorSigma[0,n]=DirichletConvolve[1,1,j,n]
```

I only recently tweeted about this to @WolframResearch https://twitter.com/ndroock1/status/1273593486491693062

Comment: Hi @nilo, yeah, for sure the documentation could be simpler - and so could the function!