# Computing an infinite sum

Tags: special-functions, summation, number-theory

I wish to compute $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)e^{-nz}$$
where $f(n)= |\{(a,b,c)| abc=n\}|$ and $z>0$. Its easy to compute that if $n = \prod p_{i}^{\alpha_i}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes then $$f(n)= \prod \binom{\alpha_i+2}{2}$$ For instance $6=2\times 3$ and we can check that the set is $$\{(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1),(6,1,1),(1,6,1),(1,1,6)\}$$ and so $f(6)=9$. I am a novice to mathematica, can anyone help me figure out how I should compute this on mathematica. Your help will be appreciated.

Edit: As suggested by J. M., I put the code
`Sum[DivisorSigma[0, n] Exp[-nz]/(1 - Exp[-nz]), {n, 1, ∞}]`, but Mathematica gives same sum as output.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I do not understand your syntax: `f(n)=|{(a,b,c)|abc=n}|` However, note: if we call the z-transform of f: fz, then your sum is: sum= fx[Exp[z]]-f[0]. fz can be obtained from the function `ZTransform`

Comment: It would be super helpful if you unpacked the math notation for me. Express it in words perhaps. For instance, I am not sure what operation the curly brace in $f(n)$ indicates. A list of the three values? Something else?

Comment: by $|\{(a,b,c)|abc=n\}|$ I mean't the cardinality of the set.

Comment: Are you aware that your sum can be expressed as a [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series)? `With[{q = Exp[-z]}, Sum[DivisorSigma[0, n] q^(n - 1)/(1 - q^n), {n, 1, ∞}] - 1]`

Comment: Marco and Daniel: OP's $f(n)$ counts the number of ways an integer $n$ can be expressed as a product of three factors.

Comment: `With[{q = Exp[-1]}, 
 NSum[DivisorSigma[0, n] q^(n - 1)/(1 - q^n), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}] - 
  1]` produces `1.94412` and a warning "General::munfl: Exp[-743.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.".

Comment: Right, *Mathematica* is not aware of a closed form for the Lambert series I gave. Thus, you need to evaluate numerically with e.g. `NSum[]`.

Comment: It is interesting that the realization of your approach by `f[n_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 Product[Binomial[FactorInteger[n][[k, 2]] + 2, 2], {k, 1, 
    Dimensions[FactorInteger[n]][[1]]}]*Exp[-n*z]; NSum[
 f[n, 1], {n, 1, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 45]` produces `1.81884103 < 1.94412`.

Comment: @user, thanks for checking; it seems I made a mistake in reindexing when I switched from the power series to the Lambert series. Assuming I didn't make any other mistakes, the correct sum should look like `With[{q = Exp[-z]}, 2 q + NSum[DivisorSigma[0, n] q^n/(1 - q^n), {n, 1, ∞}]]`

Comment: @J.M. I find the connection to the Lambert function very interesting, I am willing to learn more about it.  Maybe you can explain (perhaps in an answer) how you obtained your formula. There is no such a formula in the wiki.

Answer (score 6):

(This got too long for a comment.)

What the OP calls $f(n)$ counts what could be called a $3$-*[multiplicative partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_partition)* of $n$. This is sometimes referred to in the literature as a *Piltz function* of order $3$ (see e.g. [this paper](https://eudml.org/doc/278958)).

In particular, the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007425) gives a convenient formula for the $3$-Piltz function:

$$f(n)=\tau_3(n)=\sum_{d \mid n} \sigma_0(d)$$

where $\sigma_0(n)$ [counts the number of divisors of $n$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html), and is implemented in *Mathematica* as `DivisorSigma[0, n]`. This is then summed all over the divisors $d$ of $n$.

In fact, this sum over all divisors can be alternately expressed as a *[Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution)* (see my previous discussion [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107664)): `DirichletConvolve[DivisorSigma[0, k], 1, k, n]`.

On the other hand, one might notice the following discrepancy:

```
With[{n = 1},
     {Apply[Times, Binomial[FactorInteger[n][[All, 2]] + 2, 2]], 
      DirichletConvolve[DivisorSigma[0, k], 1, k, n]}]
   {3, 1}
```

which can lead to different results depending on which form is used. To make things easy for myself, I will continue with the second representation.

As is customary, I let $q=\exp(-z)$ and consider the generating function

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tau_3(n)q^n$$

An important identity that can be exploited here relates normal generating functions and so-called *[Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series)*:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n q^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \frac{q^n}{1-q^n}\quad\text{if}\quad c_n=\sum_{d \mid n} a_d$$

which means the generating function of $\tau_3(n)$ can be expressed as the Lambert series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_0(n) \frac{q^n}{1-q^n}$$

(I mentioned the discrepancy between the two different versions of $\tau_3(n)$ earlier; one only needs to add or subtract a $2q$ term as needed.)

Some limited numerical experiments I did suggest that the Lambert form is more tractable than the OP's original generating function form, especially for small $q$ (corresponding to large $z$); perhaps someone with more time and inclination than me can do more detailed comparisons.